# How to make this module compatible with requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am porting one of my old javascript file to compatible with requireJS. This is previously how the code looks like.

```
// effect.js
(function(exports){

    // shorthand
    exports.effect = function(selector) {
        return new Effect(selector);
    };

    // init
    exports.Effect = function(selector){
        this.target = document.getElementById(selector);        
    };

    Effect.prototype.run = function(){
        alert('halo');
    };
})(this);

//invoke it with
effect('box').run();
```

Tried to make it compatible with requireJS:

```
// effect.js
define(function(exports){   
    // Shorthand
    exports.effect = function(selector) {
        return new Effect(selector);
    };

    // init
    exports.Effect = function(selector){
        alert('halo');
        this.target = document.getElementById(selector);        
    };

    Effect.prototype.run = function(){
        alert('halo');
    };      
}

// require js
require([
    'effect.js'
],function(Effect){
    effect('box').run();
})
```

The code above won't run, how do I achieve the same result with just running shorthand of effect('box').run().

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was satisfactory, or highlight any further issues you need help with, cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
define(function() {

    // init
    var Effect = function(selector) {
        this.target = document.getElementById(selector);
    };

    Effect.prototype.run = function(){
        alert('halo');
    };

    // Replaces the 'shorthand' function from the first example 
    // This is returned as a module to the require call
    return function(selector) {
        return new Effect(selector);
    }

});

require(['effect.js'], function(effect) {
    effect('box').run();
});
```